# web scrape through an input form

Tags: python, web-scraping, solarwindslem

I'm a beginner to web scraping and although I can do it to an average webpage, I've tried in both node.js and python to scrape Solarwinds but it only returns the login page despite giving the correct login credentials.

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2 
import cookielib

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.open("******")



br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['username'] = '***'
br.form['password'] = '***'
br.submit()

print br.response().read()
```

I always get this error `mechanize._form.ControlNotFoundError: no control matching name 'username'`

Comment: Can you link the page that you're trying to scrape?

Comment: Are you sure the form you're selecting has a "username" field? Are you sure the first form on the page is the one you want?

Comment: @spruceb Thanks, it was the username field. Once I inspected the element I realised under name it was called something different.